# can't Call C# class from Powershell 3.0

Tags: c#, powershell

I created a simple C# class to learn how to call C# class from powershell script. I compiled that project as "Class Library" and copied onto my C:\ drive.

Googled around and found that we need to register that .DLL with powershell using the following command.

```
 PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> [Reflecion.Assembly]::LoadFile("C:\Calculator.dll")

PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $ml = new-object Calculator()
       At line:1 char:29
      + $ml = new-object Calculator()
       +                             ~
   An expression was expected after '('.
+ CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], 
 ParentContainsErrorRecordException
   + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ExpectedExpression
```

I don't get any errors after that command.
When I try to access the class like this, I get error.
new to powershell. any suggestions please? Thanks

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;


namespace Calculator
{
    public class Calculator
    {
    #region "Private Data Members"

        private int _operandA;
        private int _operandB;

    #endregion "Private Data Members"

        public int OperandA
        {
            get { return _operandA; }
            set { _operandA = value; }
        }     

        public int OperandB
        {
            get { return _operandB; }
            set { _operandB = value; }
        }

        public void AddNumbers(int a, int b)
        {
            int c;
            c = a + b;
            MessageBox.Show("The addition of 2 operands is c");
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: Remove the () from new object

Answer (score 4):

You should add-type and then create the new object.
based on your C# you namespace is Calculator and you will need to call the class from that namespace is make sure you add another calculator to your **New-Object**

```
Add-Type -Path 'C:\Calculator'
New-Object Calculator.Calculator
```

a working example is

```
Add-Type -Path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\System.Management.dll'
$Management = new-object System.Management.Instrumentation.Instrumentation
$Management
```

> Output : System.Management.Instrumentation.Instrumentation

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to instantiate with `()`, and you also need to qualify the namespace your class was defined in.

```
PS> [Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile("C:\Calculator.dll")
PS> $ml = new-object Calculator.Calculator
```